# Convert Multiset to a Map

Tags: java, collections, guava

I have to convert a [Guava `Multiset<String>`](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained) to a `Map<String, Integer>` (Key, Count).

I cannot find any utility function for this. Is there anything shorter than my code below for this?

```
private static Map<String, Integer> multisetToMap(final Multiset<String> multiset) {
    Map<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<>();
    for(String element: multiset.elementSet()) {
        result.put(element, multiset.count(element));
    }
    return ImmutableMap.copyOf(result);
}
```

Comment: Might be better to post this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. One observation is to use an `ImmutableMap.Builder` instead of populating the `HashMap` and then copying it.

Comment: @PaulBellora ```Collections.unmodifiableMap()``` is also an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, there's no hidden Guava feature for this, and you're doing basically the right thing.

I did not spot a feature request (open or otherwise) for doing exactly this either. But if we ever implement [this feature request](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=1676) you might have another alternative.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use an [Eclipse Collections](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/) (formerly GS Collections) Bag (which is equivalent to Multiset), you can use the method `toMapOfItemToCount()`.

```
HashBag<Integer> bag = HashBag.newBagWith(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3);
Map<Integer,Integer> map = bag.toMapOfItemToCount();
Assert.assertEquals(UnifiedMap.newWithKeysValues(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3), map);
```

UnifiedMap is a drop-in replacement for HashMap.

**Note:** I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.